# Multisample framebuffer failed to make in GLKView error 8cdd

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, multisampling, glkview

I'm currently creating a GLKView that is above another view where i draw some lines on.
But i have got a strange problem.
For my task i need to use multi-sampling which is done by this line

```
self.drawableMultisample = GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X;
```

in my constructor.
On the simulator on iOS 7.1/7/6.1 i got the expected result.
On an iPad Mini 1 i get the same result.

Edit:
iPad 2 also works.

But if i use an iPad 1 (5.1) or an iPad 4 (7.1) i get the following error.

**Failed to make complete multisample framebuffer object 8cdd**

if i check the error with

```
GLuint returned = glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES);
NSLog(@"Error code: %x -->", returned);
```

i get **Error code: 8219** on the iPad 4 and **Error code: 8cdd** on the iPad 1

and no drawing is done of course. If i disable multi-sampling there is no error.
This class is used in a big project and is subclassed. Using the super class itself does not solve the problem. The GLK is completely done in code only its superview which is a simple UIView is a .xib file.

If i use the class in a new project by making a GLKView in the Storyboard as my class, multi-sampling works fine.

If any further informations are needed don't hesitate to ask.
Thanks in advance.

Update:

There seems to be a problem after setting the frame of the GLKView but only on non A5-Chip Devices.

Comment: [Multisampling](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/opengl-macprogguide/opengl_fsaa/opengl_fsaa.html) is limited depending on the device you use [link](http://lists.apple.com/archives/mac-opengl/2005/Apr/msg00169.html) add maxMultisampling result to you init.

Comment: Same code works in a new project, your answer is right but does not help me

Comment: At least try it, it will not hurt to have that check permanently.

Comment: The methods described in your link are not available in the GLKit.

Comment: i meant OpenGLES framework by Apple instead of GLKit.